# Data Studio - Calculate Fields - Substraction of Total Events

Tags: calculated-field, looker-studio

I would like to create a calculated field, which would substract metrics total events from the event with more total events to event with less total events. Afterwards, I would like to create a line graph of this in DataStudio.

Basically, I would like to substract total events of the following events:

```
Event Category: Game

Event Action: Game Session Started

minus

Event Category: Game

Event Action: Game Session Finished
```

I was trying in CASE with functions such as ABS, SUM etc.. however, I can't seem to find a solution. Thank you.

Here is an example:
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/z3q39.png)

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sum(case 
WHEN Event_Category = 'Game' and Event_Action='Game Session Started' THEN 'Total Events'
ELSE 0 END)
-
sum(case 
WHEN Event_Category = 'Game' and Event_Action='Game Session Finished' THEN 'Total Events'
ELSE 0 END)
```

You may need to split into 2 calculated metrics and then use a 3rd to minus the finished from the started.

Comment: I created two calculated metrics (basically split your formula) and the another calculated metric (one minus the other) but the results is still empty.

Comment: My first calculated field is:
SUM(CASE WHEN Event Category = 'Game' and Event Action ='Game Session Started' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

My 2nd calculated field is:
SUM(CASE WHEN Event Category = 'Game' and Event Action ='Game Session Finished' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Comment: When i add this in the table, the number is only 1.

Comment: If you add it to a table with the "Event Category" and "Event Action" dimensions and a count of one of those dimensions, what do you get?

Comment: My table is then:
Dimension1: Event Category
Dimension2: Event Action
Metric: Calculated Metric - SUM(CASE WHEN Event Category = 'Game' and Event Action ='Game Session Started' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) - but as usual it shows just 1.

Comment: Did you add the count() field? Can you pop up a picture too?

Comment: Current status: Field 1:

SUM(CASE WHEN Event Category = 'Game' and Event Action ='Game Session Started' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Field 2: SUM(CASE WHEN Event Category = 'Game' and Event Action ='Game Session Finished' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)

Field 3: Test - Game Session Started-Test - Game Session Finished

Where should I use the count? Not in the connection of sum, or ? Thanks for help! As far as I know, re-aggregating metrics is not possible in DataStudio

Comment: Just add the count field to a table. So you'd have a table with dimensions - Event Category, Event Action and metrics - Field 1, field 2, field 3, count(event category)

Comment: Okay, that helps. I've edited my answer, see if that helps.

Comment: Just having a second look at the picture, it suggests your data is already rolled up into groups of Event Category and Event Action rather than at a hit level. Is that the case?

Comment: All the events have same event category/event action, the only split is on event label (there were have different values). The edited version also shows the invalid formula.

Comment: Doing this directly on a GA source gives "Sorry, calculated fields can't mix metrics (aggregated values) and dimensions (non-aggregated values). Please check the aggregation types of the fields used in this formula. [Learn more](https://support.google.com/datastudio/answer/7569962#troubleshoot-calculated-fields&zippy=%2Cin-this-article)."

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60882284/1913230) solved it for me

Answer (score 0):

I think this may not be feasible to do, however as you requested:

**Field 1** - `SUM(CASE WHEN Event Category = 'Game' and Event Action ='Game Session Started' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

**Field 2** - `SUM(CASE WHEN Event Category = 'Game' and Event Action ='Game Session Finished' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)`

**Field 3** - `(Field 1 - Field 2)`

**Field 4** - `Count(Event Category)`

[Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UasCb.png)

Comment: "re-aggregating not supported"

Answer (score 0):

in my case, recommendations with *SUM(CASE WHEN Event Category = 'Game' and Event Action ='Game Session Started' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)* didn't work because basically, we need to mix dimensions with metrics...

in the best case it has to be something like this:
CASE WHEN Event Category = 'Game' and Event Action ='Game Session Started' THEN {{UNIQUE EVENTS}} ELSE 0 END
but it does not work because we mix Event Category / Event Action (dimensions) with calculated result {{UNIQUE EVENTS}} (metric) - maybe in the future, it will work...

To fix this task, I did next:
1 created 2 independent tables, each of them filtering by a specific event
2 blend data adding 3rd table with a date for the shared timeline
3 in blended data source - calculated SUM(Total Events (game start))-SUM(Total Events (game finished))

[chart](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U4YJe.png)

[data blending settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HTlEL.png)

[filter for one table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbFbm.png)